# How to write C .so library to subsitute existing C++ .so library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries

Let me explain the scenario. We have a legacy C++ compiled .so library. The functions in this library are declared with `extern "c" {}`, so the library can be used by both C and C++ program, plus, for some reason it was created with`--static-libgcc` option.

This old library is very old and hard to maintain. Now we haved managed to write a subsitution of it, but in C language. Let's say the old library is called libfoo.so(old), and new one is libfoo.so(new). For a given bar.o, it can be linked with either old or new libfoo.so to create a executable, say, bar.exe. But the bar.exe can only run with the same .so library it linked before, by the other words, these two libraries are not mutual exchangable.

**EDIT#1**: I made a symbolic link named libfoo.so to point to libfoo.so(old) or libfoo.so(new). This symbolic link libfoo.so is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime.

**EDIT#2**: When I linked bar.o with old libfoo.so and generated bar.exe, if I run this bar.exe with new libfoo.so, it reported error of `undefined symbols`. By `nm` these two libfoo.so, I can find out these symbols in old one, but not in new one. The symbols are something like `_ZSt4cerr`, which is a C++ lib mangled name(I though it was brought by `--static-libgcc`), and of course the new libfoo.so does not contains those kind of symbols.

**EDIT#3**: If I just compile and link the C code with g++ instead of gcc, does it make any sense?

How should I implement this?

**EDIT#4**: Today I managed to compile/link the new C programed libfoo with g++ (with static libgcc, static libstdc++), this can lead to all c++ symbols to be contained in libfoo.so. This can make everything run smoothly, but not what I really want.

Comment: Why doesn't it run with the new library? What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: He's not getting an error message. He's fixing something that isn't broken, just clunking loudly.

Comment: Please refer to EDIT#2, I have updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Anybody know the solution here? I really really need one. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you build and link with the new one, can you get it to link with the old one?  It sounds like you generated a binary compatible library, but only in one direction.

Comment: Yes. If I build and link with the new library, produced bar.exe can run with both old and new library. But why?

Comment: This means that the header files of the new library depend on less symbols than those of the old library.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html might provide some more insight in what and how of binary compatible shared libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Edit#2 helps.

Basically your *bar.exe* is trying to do the C++ runtime initialization for that library.

You will have to, at a minimum, provide empty implementations of identically mangled names so that the *bar.exe* can dynamically search your .so and find/call them.

If you are less lucky, you might need to actually have those functions do something meaningful that the up-level code interprets as success.

Good Luck

Comment: Or, simpler answer, C .so replacing C++ .so is not practical...? :(

Answer (score 0):

give them same name and put into different directories. use LD_LIBRARY_PATH env. variable to set directory with desired library before any other directories.